# CentOS VPS : how to enable PermitRootLogin

Tags: centos, ssh, vps

While logged-in in to "root" via ssh I disabled PermitRootLogin setting in /etc/ssh/sshd_config file.

It was advised to do so in the Cpanel's security adviser.
Now I want to re-enable it for short period.

But because I've already disabled "rootLogin" by setting `PermitRootLogin no` ,I cant access /etc/ssh/sshd_config file to edit.
Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: SSH with other user and than do su and enter password and enable root login in sshd_config.

Answer (score 0):

Usually hosting providers have a javascript based shell. Login to the VPS using the webbased client and edit the sshd_config file.